# Superposition with dependent sources

Tags: circuit-analysis, current-source, voltage-source, superposition

If the value of a dependent source (say CCCS) depends on the value of an independent source (say a current source). When setting the current source to 0, would that make the CCCS an open circuit (i.e. set to zero) as well?

Cheers

Comment: Given that ideal current sources have infinite impedance, a current source set to zero is indistinguishable from an open circuit, since it has infinite impedance *and* injects no current. Thus, for the specific case you mention, the independent source set to 0 makes the dependent source same as an open circuit. But that's only because you got a dependent current source. This is not the case for dependent voltage sources, which, when set to 0, are indistinguishable from a short circuit.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean CCCS (current controlled current source)?

The answer is to treat the CCCS as you would any other source acting alone, i.e. generating it's specified current, say \$kI_x\$, which is dependent on the current in the nominated path, \$I_x\$. You must not use the trivial solution, \$I_x =0\$ at this stage; doing so is a common error.

Comment: Sorry I meant CCCS. Lets say that there is a current source providing current I1, and a dependent source (CCCS) which its current is equal to 3*I1. If we sat the current source to zero (I1=0; open circuit), wouldn't the CCCS be an open circuit too?

Comment: No. Dependent sources are treated in the same way as independent sources. Note the final sentence of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The general rule when the superposition principle is applied to a circuit having dependent-sources is NEVER switch-off these dependent-sources, unless the relevant independent source (from which they're depending) is switched-off.

Therefore, while applying the superposition principle, and you are considering ***as active an independent source*** (that is, it's **ON**), then **the related dependent-source (if any) MUST BE MAINTAINED AS SWITCHED ON**.

On the contrary, **a dependent-source (if any) MUST BE MAINTAINED AS SWITCHED OFF** **if the *associated* independent source is not ACTIVE** (that is, it is OFF).

I do hope that the above does not confuse you...but dependent-sources should be treated on a ***particular way***, and an extreme care **MUST** be used with them.